# Achieve manager like view of compressed files in Terminal

Tags: command-line, compression

If I can, I will avoid using the GUI to get around my system, and recently what I have found very annoying is that I seem unable to view the contents and open the contents of a compressed file without decompressing like the GUI application Achieve manager seems to manage to do, although I suspect that it temporarily decompresses the contents of the compressed file into another location and then allows you to browse the contents of the compressed file without having to decompress the contents first into the directory that you are in.

So what I am wondering is if there is any way that I can in Terminal view the contents of a compressed file without actually having to decompress it into a location myself (so that I can get a Terminal view of what Achieve manager does without having to launch a GUI)?